# Graceful GC with Proxy/Caching

Tags: java, caching, garbage-collection

I am designing a framework where as part of the same, I am doing a very simple compact cache pool of objects to improve performance and spiking of objects getting created and collected.

To be more specific, the logic is more like a LRU `List<?>` abstracted with a pool manager that provides `acquire()` and `release()` for the consumers/ developers on this framework. The cached items are also wrapped with a proxy (for the purpose of an internal interface for specific methods are intercepted for better object collection).

This approach works good if the developers are disciplined to call `release()` everytime and we all know there will be kids who will habitually forget this.

So I want to have the ability to check if the reference to cached item 'acquired' is only my pool manager (lets say the consumer had put `cacheRef = null;` or the `cacheRef` has gone out of scope. That way, I can manage the cache item back to pool or GC based on its TTL.

This becomes quite critical, in the light of those forgetful kids, the pool will soon be exhausted and service can go down when prospective consumers can no longer access these service objects.

Thanks in advance for tips and pointers to get this realised.

Comment: You want to use [phantom references](http://www.kdgregory.com/index.php?page=java.refobj) and log an error if that safety net had to be used (vs explicit release).

Comment: @BenManes thanks for your pointer. Must admit, I do not understand `WeakReference` or `PhantomReference` enough to achieve what I want... some queries in my mind are:
1. If create a `PhantomReference` and use `ReferenceQueue` how exactly am I returning the object to the type being requested for?
2. As long as my cache manager has a strong reference to the cached object, there will be no GC (I am pretty sure about this). Hence my doubt on whether Weak or Phantom Reference will work in my case.

Is there any particular article or blogpost that you would recommend for a dummy?

Comment: Ben Manes, congratulations for your answer. Realy useful article.

Comment: @SathyaSN See the article's example, which is exactly what you are trying to do. The resource proxy is GC'd, not the resource, and used to identify a resource leak. If the proxy is `released` then you remove the phantom reference mapping and `clear` it. Otherwise you detect the leak, clean-up, and log the error.

Comment: @BenManes Thanks a ton for your help... I get the picture now... Will have to test a few times now to feel comfortable. How do I mark your answer as correct? or credit/kudos for your help?

Comment: @SathyaSN Just keep having fun learning. I don't pay much attention to the reputation game.